# How to update a linear-gradient dynamically using Tailwind CSS and Framer Motion?

Tags: tailwind-css, react-typescript, framer-motion

I'm trying to create a range slider component using React, TypeScript, Tailwind CSS and Framer Motion.

[Link to Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-range-slider-7uu5o5?file=/src/App.js:574-668)

The above code is using useMotionTemplate to update the background of the progressbar.

`let background = useMotionTemplate`linear-gradient(90deg, #374151 ${progress}px, #d1d5db 0)`;`

Instead of using useMotionTemplate, I need to implement the same functionality using Tailwind classes or custom css to make the slider work with various color themes.

`bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-800 to-gray-500 from-[${200}px] to-0%`

[Range Slider with static background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bldPC.png)

I need to update the linear-gradient dynamically after each drag ends. I'm looking to use Tailwind classes as much as possible without using custom CSS.